# Plotly subplots of boxplot in for-loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop, plotly, boxplot, subplot

How can I make subplots by using a for loop when the traces for each individual subplot are already created using a for loop, what I got so far:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio 
import kaleido 
pio.renderers.default='browser' #change to browser or svg
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'in1' : [100, 150, 110, 180, 125], 
                   'in2' : [200, 210, 125, 125, 293],
                   'in3' : [50, 35, 200, 100, 180]
                   })

a = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g']
df1t = df1.T
df1t.columns= a

fig = make_subplots()

for col in df1t:
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df1t[col].values, name=str(df1t[col].name)))
    
fig.show()
```

But I have multiple dataframes named df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8 and df9 which are plotted in the same way as above with column name a. I want to make subplots of each df.

Answer (score 0):

- have synthesised 9 additional data frames per your specification
- construct a **dict** of all defined variables df1 to df9. This is to enable simple looping
- now just a simple case of creating all the traces across all the data frames after creating the figure with appropriate number of rows

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import kaleido
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pio.renderers.default = "browser"  # change to browser or svg
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "in1": [100, 150, 110, 180, 125],
        "in2": [200, 210, 125, 125, 293],
        "in3": [50, 35, 200, 100, 180],
    }
)

# fmt: off
df2 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df3 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df4 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df5 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df6 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df7 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df8 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
df9 = pd.DataFrame((df1.values * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=df1.shape)).astype(int),columns=df1.columns)
# fmt: on

# create dictionary of dataframes, by inspecting defined variables
dfs = {
    varname: eval(varname)
    for varname in dir()
    if varname[0:2] == "df" and len(varname) == 3 and varname[2] in "123456789"
}

a = ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

# create sub-plots based on number of dataframes
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(dfs.keys()))

# add traces to appropriate subplot for dataframe
for r, df in enumerate(dfs.values()):
    df1t = df.T
    df1t.columns = a

    for col in df1t:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Box(y=df1t[col].values, name=str(df1t[col].name)), row=r + 1, col=1
        )

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, I still got a question: what to do if the individual dataframes are not in a larger dataframe dfs? So what to do if df1 till df9 are separate dataframes?

Comment: they are separate data frames in this code...  have grouped the separate data frames in a dict instead of variables to avoid very low level python to inspect what variables are defined.  there is a dataframe constructor `pd.DataFrame()` for each df1...df9

Comment: Yes I understand, but I mean if the dataframes are variables instead in a dict

Comment: ok - have updated answer to now use inspection of defined variables, IMHO not a good way to go but seems to be a mandatory requirement